# Picking a random name from DB without repeat until all names are used

Tags: php

Hey there StackOverflow community 
as the title says , I have a table in my DB with 2 columns ID and Name.
there is a html form with a button, by clicking the button I want it to pick a name.
by clicking again , it picks a name without repeat until all names are used.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
<?php 
include ("config.php");
$result = '';

if (isset($_POST['rand'])) {
    $name_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $name_f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_query);
    $result = $name_f['name'];
}
 ?>

 <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="submit" name="rand">
 </form>

<div><?php echo $result;?></div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort by something random, then pull off the top for each request.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where's your code? Where does it fail?

Comment: @kerbholz here is the code.

Comment: What is your error ? Mysql query looks fine.

Comment: @Roshnihegde it picks repetitive names , I want the names to be returned without repeat until all names are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way to do that is creating a text file and save names in it whenever you fetch for the latter in the database. Then for subsequent fetching, check whether the name exists in the file content or not.

```
$result = '';

function getName(){
   $file_path = "file.txt";
   $where = "";
   if(file_exists($file_path)){
       $lines = file($file_path);
       if(count($lines) > 0){
          $where = " WHERE `name` NOT IN(".implode(',', $lines).") ";
       }
   }
   $name_query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `names` $where ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
   if(mysqli_num_rows($name_query) > 0){
       $name_f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($name_query);
       $result = $name_f['name'];
       file_put_contents($file_path, $result.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
       return $result;
   }else{
      file_put_contents($file_path, "");
      return getName();
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['rand'])) {
   $result = getName();
}


<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="submit" name="rand">
 </form>

<div><?php echo $result;?></div>
```